# want to know ssl is working or not in magento

Tags: security, magento, ssl

Ii have purchase an SSL certificate for my site and in the admin I set the secure  base url to https and unsecure base url to http and enable for the frontend. now i am not sure is it working fine or not. when i come to checkout it shifts to https. this is the link of my site  http://majorcomfort.com/index.php/ Please tell me is it fine or i have to do something else ....

Comment: You have purchased an SSL *certificate,*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine, the checkout steps and the customer area are under the secured URLs, which is the standard setting for Magento's "SSL enabled for frontend".

The SSL protection in the front-end is defined in the XML config under the node
`<config><frontend><secure_url>path</secure_url></frontend></config>`

where path is the desired URL,e.g. `/customer/` for the customer area, or `/checkout/onepage`, for the checkout

Comment: i've just done a test order, the checkout seems to be fine, SSL-wise